# Javascript URL Parameter Selector Not Working

Tags: javascript

Trying to change "Recent Posts" to "More Posts" on offset url pages, and I can't figure out why this won't work.

https://noahlangphotography.com/blog?offset=1663616760983

`<script> if (window.location.search.includes("offset")) { document.querySelector('#block-638064e4cae107c42e91b95e h1').innerHTML = 'More Posts'; } </script>`

I expected it to say "More Posts"

[Noah L.](https://noahlangphotography.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use,

```
(window.location.href.includes("offset"))
```

instead of

```
(window.location.search.includes("offset"))
```